# Looking to add a background inside logo, but not outside

Tags: colors, adobe-illustrator, pathfinder, background

[logo with transparent interior and background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hx2lg.png)

I have the blue background offset so you can see the logo in transparent. Essentially I want the inside of the wheel and text to be blue, but I do not want any of the blue on the outside of the logo.

I am not a graphic artist so I did some research and started to tinker with creating a blue square for the background and sending it to the back. Then I tinkered with the pathfinder as well as clipping masks to get the desired effect. No go. Again, I am very amateur so any advice on how to do this is welcome. I feel for someone who knows what they are doing that this would b e an easy task.

The image below is what I am going for except I would like the blue inside the triangular sections inside the wheel as well.

[desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o87xV.png)

Comment: almost like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGfsB.png

Comment: That is what I want it to look like. Do you have a guide or steps on how to achieve this in illustrator?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if I've missed something (I work in Raster illustration programs *way more often* then I do in Vector design ones), but what is stopping you from simply placing a layer below everything, using the magic wand tool (or something equivalent) to select the triangle section, and filling the selection with blue?

That's how I would do it.

Comment: The triangular areas are not anything but artboard and cannot be selected.